# Conflicting second derivatives for quadratic equation

Tags: derivatives, quadratics

I just cannot wrap my head around this.

I encounter this issue when trying to understand the quadratic approximation and I don't seem to find a good explanation of where the 1/2 coefficient comes from by using the definition of derivatives and I think that may be related to the below?

Let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$
so the $f'(x)=2ax+b$ and if we take the derivative of $f'(x)$ then $f''(x)=2a$

However, if we use the definition of derivatives
$$f'(x)=\lim \limits_{x \to k}  \frac{f(x)-f(k)}{x-k}$$
$$f'(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to k}  \frac{ax^2+bx+c-ak^2-bk-c}{x-k}$$
$$f'(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to k}  \frac{a(x^2-k^2)+b(x-k)}{x-k}$$
$$f'(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to k}  \frac{a(x+k)(x-k)+b(x-k)}{x-k}$$
$$f'(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to k}  a(x+k)+b$$
if we stop here and don't make x+k =2x but apply the definition of derivative on this again

we will get:
$$f''(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to k} \lim \limits_{x \to k} \frac{a(x+k)+b-a(k+k)-b}{x-k}$$
$$f''(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to k} \lim \limits_{x \to k} \frac{a(x+k-k-k)}{x-k}$$
$$f''(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to k} \lim \limits_{x \to k} \frac{a(x-k)}{x-k}$$
$$f''(x) = a$$

Where do I get it wrong?

Comment: First, you should use $\lim_{k\to x}$, not $\lim_{x\to k}$.

Comment: While $\lim \limits_{x \to k} \lim \limits_{x \to k}$ is not clear as to whether it is a duplication or two limits

Comment: @GEdgar it just flips the sign, doesn't it? so every expression of x-k becomes k-x. It doesn't affect the coefficient

Comment: From $f'(x) = \lim \limits_{k \to x}  a(x+k)+b$ you might say $f''(x)=\lim \limits_{w \to x}\left(\dfrac{\lim\limits_{k \to x}  (a(x+k)+b) - \lim\limits_{j \to w}  (a(w+j)+b)}{x-w}\right)$ $=a+a\lim \limits_{w \to x}\left(\dfrac{\lim\limits_{k \to x}  k - \lim\limits_{j \to w}  j}{x-w}\right) $ $= 2a$

Comment: @Henry hmm, so w->x, k->w, j->w, if you combine the numerator, it becomes $\lim \limits_{k \to x}\lim \limits_{j \to w} a(x+k-w-j)$ the same issue will happen.

Comment: @YeGu No.  $\lim \limits_{k \to x}\lim \limits_{j \to w} a(x+k-w-j) = a(2x-2w)$ which you can happily divide by $x-w$ to get $2a$ before you take $\lim \limits_{w \to x}$

Comment: @Henry thank you for the explanation and I understand the correct answer is 2a. But the thing is that since w->x,k->x,j->w, then k must also approach w or j must also approach x. Then (x+(k-w)-j) = (x-j). So where exactly went wrong in my logic?

Comment: Hi Henry, I think I figured it out by using this definition $f'(x) = \lim \limits_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta )-f(x)}{\Delta}$ By doing this, I will always have two $\Delta$ after cancellation no matter what. Thanks anyway.